# Populate Array with values from another arrray

Tags: array, oop

I have retrieved WP_Post object and i stored it in a variable.

```
Array
(
[0] => WP_Post Object
    (
        [ID] => 45
        [post_author] => 1
        [post_date] => 2014-03-10 14:22:01
        [post_date_gmt] => 2014-03-10 14:22:01
        [post_content] => 
        [post_title] => sddddddddddd
        [post_excerpt] => 
        [post_status] => publish
        [comment_status] => closed
        [ping_status] => closed
        [post_password] => 
        [post_name] => sddddddddddd
        [to_ping] => 
        [pinged] => 
        [post_modified] => 2014-03-10 14:23:57
        [post_modified_gmt] => 2014-03-10 14:23:57
        [post_content_filtered] => 
        [post_parent] => 0
        [guid] => http://localhost/bitbucket/?post_type=advertisement&p=45
        [menu_order] => 0
        [post_type] => advertisement
        [post_mime_type] => 
        [comment_count] => 0
        [filter] => raw
    )

[1] => WP_Post Object
    (
        [ID] => 40
        [post_author] => 1
        [post_date] => 2014-03-10 11:00:28
        [post_date_gmt] => 2014-03-10 11:00:28
        [post_content] => 
        [post_title] => 123
        [post_excerpt] => 
        [post_status] => publish
        [comment_status] => closed
        [ping_status] => closed
        [post_password] => 
        [post_name] => 123
        [to_ping] => 
        [pinged] => 
        [post_modified] => 2014-03-10 12:49:24
        [post_modified_gmt] => 2014-03-10 12:49:24
        [post_content_filtered] => 
        [post_parent] => 0
        [guid] => http://localhost/bitbucket/?post_type=advertisement&p=40
        [menu_order] => 0
        [post_type] => advertisement
        [post_mime_type] => 
        [comment_count] => 0
        [filter] => raw
    )

[2] => WP_Post Object
    (
        [ID] => 37
        [post_author] => 1
        [post_date] => 2014-03-05 13:56:15
        [post_date_gmt] => 2014-03-05 13:56:15
        [post_content] => 
        [post_title] => asd
        [post_excerpt] => 
        [post_status] => publish
        [comment_status] => closed
        [ping_status] => closed
        [post_password] => 
        [post_name] => asd
        [to_ping] => 
        [pinged] => 
        [post_modified] => 2014-03-10 14:26:23
        [post_modified_gmt] => 2014-03-10 14:26:23
        [post_content_filtered] => 
        [post_parent] => 0
        [guid] => http://bitbucket/?post_type=advertisement&p=37
        [menu_order] => 0
        [post_type] => advertisement
        [post_mime_type] => 
        [comment_count] => 0
        [filter] => raw
    )
```

)

Well the above is my object. Now i need to store some values from it in a custom array which would look like:

```
$my_array = array (
               ID => post_title
            );
```

and ID and post_title should be from the object above. How can i accomplish this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can easily use `foreach` to achieve that,

```
$my_array = array();
foeach($wpArray as $row){
   $my_array[$row->ID] = $row->post_name;
}
```

Comment: well this was enlightening :)